# npm install on Ubuntu showing error

Tags: ubuntu, npm, server

I uploaded my website on Ubuntu server and it contains `package.json`.
Now I want to install all dependencies using `npm install` in my website directory.

My website is not in the root folder. Node and NPM are already installed on my server.

The following is the error I am getting when I run `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat '/root'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/mywebsite
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /root
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR! makeCacheDir homeless?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/mywebsite/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need root account. Try running with `sudo`.

```
sudo npm install
```

Comment: I have root account and I tried to run command with sudo, but it shows same error. I installed npm on my root and then I went to directory (where my website is located), and then I run 'sudo npm install', and I am getting same error.

npm and node is installed on my server.

Comment: What the error? The one you showed above? Is /root directory does exists?

Comment: above error is shown when I tried **sudo npm install**. Also, I have root  directory on my server